# Синоним или нет?

Tags: синонимы

"Автострада" — это синоним слова "дорога" или гипоним?

Answer (score 1):

Естественно, гипоним. Нешто всякая дорога автострада?!

Comment: Спасибо, я вот тоже пришла к этой мысли, хоть и не филолог, но в детском кружке по русскому языку меня пытаются уверить, что автострада это синоним дорога, снизив ребенку балл за ответы.

Comment: Тем не менее, словари говорят, что "автострада" — это синоним слова "дорога". Например: http://trishin.net/ Может быть, гипонимы надо рассматривать как подкласс синонимов? Тем более, в рамках средней школы.

Comment: Если в рамках средней школы изучают гипонимы, значит,  их интересует именно этот вид отношений между словами, сходными по значению.  Вероятно, дорога — это самое общее понятие,  а все остальные  шоссе, бетонки, тропы и тропинки —  гипонимы.

Comment: Полностью задание выглядело так:

Comment: полностью задание было такое: Перед вами отрывок из стихотворения «Дорога» Всеволода Остена.

Дорогой зовут автостраду,
И тропку, бегущую рядом,
И шлях, что лежит на равнине,
Путь каравана в пустыне….

Сколько в этом отрывке синонимов к слову дорога?

ТРебуемый ответ был такой:

Автострада – широкая прямая дорога, предназначенная для скоростного движения автомобилей;
Тропка – узкая протоптанная дорожка;
Шлях – на Украине и на юге России степная дорога у южных границ;
Путь – полоса земли, предназначенная для передвижения.

Comment: Объясните мне с позиции логики, пожалуйста. Путь каравана в пустыне, это же не конкретная "дорога", а дорога в общем смысле? Шлях - иностранное слово, вроде как значится синонимом "дорога". А вот тропка или автострада - это частные примеры дороги или я что-то в филологии не понимаю совсем :)

Comment: правильный ответ, приведенный выше, резюмируется так: в тексте 4 синонима слову дорога

Comment: Материал из Интернета: Путь в пустыне проходил по КАРАВАННЫМ ТРОПАМ, которые имели различный вид. Это могли быть едва заметные в песках тропы, проложенные с незапамятных времен . Если почва глинистая - тропа была глубокая и узкая,  оттиснутая верблюжьими лапами, также  встречались каменистые участки пути. Как караванщики ориентировались в пустыне среди постоянно меняющихся барханов? В караване обязательно присутствовали несколько ослов-проводников, которые вели караван к ближайшему городу, колодцу или оазису на пути.

Answer (score 1):

Многие ответы **можно найти в словаре**, который всегда можно использовать в качестве доказательства:

**ДОРОГА,** 1. Полоса земли, служащая для езды и ходьбы. **АВТОМАГИСТРАЛЬ**,  Широкая многополосная скоростная **дорога** без пересечений и перекрестков для движения автомобилей; автострада.

Дорога — общее понятие, а автострада (автомагистраль) — частное, поэтому автострада — это гипоним.

Comment: Все же хотелось бы понять, гипоним - это частный случай синонима или нет (см. мой комментарий к вопросу)?

Comment: Синонимы и гипонимы - это разные парадигматические отношения.

Синонимы обозначают близкие по значению слова,  а гипонимы и гиперонимы - это родо-видовые отношения. http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/leksikologia/slovo-znachenie/giperonimi-i-giponimi/690/?q=463&n=690

Comment: @ Sibylla. Как вы объясните тот факт, что гипонимы показаны как синонимы в словарях синонимов, например  автомагистраль - как синоним дороги.